# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, token

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have a form that a user can submit.

I am not using the Form helper, but I made sure I included this in all my form blade views:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

When I go to the webpage with the form on it, it displays the form as expected, then I submit it, it works as expected.

Another case is, I go to the webpage, I walk away and come back 30 minutes later and try to submit the form and I am presented with the error. I am pretty sure it is because the token expired, but what I am trying to do is to check if the token is expired, re-direct the user to the same page (which refreshes the token) with an error message that explains that the form had expired.

In theory, on submit, check:

```
if token expired
  return redirect('login')->with('error', 'The form expired, please try again');
endif
```

Is there a way to check for that instead of displaying Laravel's default error screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom behaviour for method `handle` in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. By default if the token is expired it throws the exception TokenMismatchException.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my Handler.php render method:

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {

    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withInput($request->except('_token'))
        ->with('status', 'The form has expired, please try again.');
}
```